# Should the order arrangement of reducers in combineReducers matter when building a redux app?

Tags: redux, react-redux

When building a redux app is it right to find dependancies between reducers passed to the combineReducers object? To be more elaborate, if I have two reducers handling different parts of the state but both listening to the same action, is it right (or possible) to arrange the reducers so that R1 is handled before R2? Or does that flag a possible design flaw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the order arrangement of reducers in combineReducers matter when building a redux app?

No. `combineReducers()` is basically just a mapping not an ordered list.

> is it right (or possible) to arrange the reducers so that R1 is handled before R2? Or does that flag a possible design flaw?

There shouldn't be any dependencies at all between reducers. If there's a dependency, that will be a design flaw.

Reducers are just concerned of updating a unique part or a slice of the entire `state` object based on an action.

If you want a sequential update of state, check [redux-saga](/questions/tagged/redux-saga) or have the component dispatch two separate actions sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been writing reducers, their order arrangement inside a `combineReducers()` call does not matter.

You could have something that looks like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  form: formReducer
});
```

Notice I have a `formReducer` from Redux Form which is not a reducer you would manually write out in your `reducers/` folder but comes with Redux Form library and also notice I imported the `formReducer` first, but I assigned it second place inside the `combineReducers` object, so no, no order necessary.

Comment: Thank you! The problem we had was a bit more abstract, there was a certain part being mutated in our state that we didn’t take note of and that produced a bug when changing the order in combineReducers, once this was noted and fixed the order didn’t matter.

Comment: @DinaNashaat, based on what you shared that sounds like it had something to do with how a particular reducer was being written that was causing mutation of state, I am happy to hear it was resolved.